# Can't display ASP.NET MVC View in Kendo pop-up window via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit a form using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC in a Kendo window and am having problems.

First, here's what works. If I make this call in the regular browser window (i.e. not in a popup iframe Kendo window)...

```
function formSubmit() {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

...the call goes through to the controller. If there are validation errors, the controller will return a new view and they will be displayed in the browser window. If the operation is successful, it returns the view to a search page. So far, so good.

Now, I want to do almost the exact same thing in a Kendo window iframe, except with some important differences:

- If there are validation errors, keep the Kendo window open until they are resolved.
- If the submit is successful and this was a Create action, return the record id of the newly-created database record via JSON and pass that value to another JavaScript function, receiveNewIDFromIFrame(). And close the Kendo window.
- If the submit is successful and this was an Edit action, return null. And close the Kendo window.

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
function inIframe() {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}

function formSubmit() {

    if (!inIframe()) {
        // We are a parent window
        $('form').submit();
    }
    else {
        // We are a pop-up window
        $.post($('form').attr("action"), $("form").serialize(), function(data){
            if (data != null) {
                if ($.isNumeric(data)) {
                    // We got back an id, so that means we need to pass it back to the parent form.
                    var rowIndex = "@Model.PopupWindowRowIndex";
                    parent.receiveNewIDFromIFrame(data, rowIndex);
                    parent.$('#window').data('kendoWindow').close(); // Close the popup window
                }
                else if (data = '') {
                    // We got back nothing, which means we were editing and we can close this window
                    parent.$('#window').data('kendoWindow').close(); // Close the popup window
                }
                else {
                    // We got back a view, so display that in the pop-up window.
                    $('form').html(data); // THIS DOESN'T WORK.
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The controller code for Create looks somewhat like this:

```
   public ActionResult Create(VMReportObservation viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    // There are validation errors.
            return View(viewModel);
        }

    // ... Save data ...

        if (viewModel.IsInPopupWindow)
        {
            return Json(reportHeader.record_id.ToString()); // Return the record ID so we know to attach it.
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Since we're in the main window, go back to the index after submitting.
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is when I receive the view back and try to populate the Kendo window via jQuery: $('form').html(data);

I am definitely getting legitimate HTML back, but all I end up seeing in the Kendo window is a < hr > divider element (which is part of the view) and nothing else. I have tried other ways to display the view that I receive back from the controller, but I've not been able to get it to display properly.

Of course, if I use my initial bit of code...

```
function formSubmit() {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

...there's no problem with seeing the view with the form validation errors. However, I lose the ability to capture the new record id in the database and the ability to know when to close the Kendo window.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried changing `$('form').html(data);` to `$(this).html(data)` but it does not replace the html in the Kendo window.

Comment: It looks like `document.write(data)` is the correct syntax (I can replace the Kendo window data with a simple hardcoded html page), but it's not showing the refreshed view from MVC, even though it's getting the data.